# Openzeppelin 2.x Crowdsale Solidity Pragma issue

Tags: solidity, hardhat

how can I compile multiple versions within one project?

currently I am developing a crowdsale repo. I want to implement the feature to let the investor claimBack their funds

So I implemented this into my Repo
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales#refundablecrowdsale

But the versions are not compatible. I tried to change pragma to same versions and tried different versions. I always get incompatibility errors.

This is the Repo
https://github.com/AwesomeEcosystem/sale/tree/Refactor

How can I fix this?

Comment: Link about your repo is broken.

Comment: argh, thanks mate

was private, is now public